# Databinding for TextWatcher is not working Android

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am making a password creation screen, and I want to show a password strength indicator as they type. 
My layout looks like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.PasswordViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:textChangedListener="@{viewModel.passwordTextWatcher}" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{viewModel.passwordQuality}"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

PasswordViewModel.java is like below

```
public class PasswordViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private String password;

    @Bindable
    public String getPasswordQuality() {
        if (password == null || password.isEmpty()) {
            return "Enter a password";
        } else if (password.equals("password")) {
            return "Very bad";
        } else if (password.length() < 6) {
            return "Short";
        } else {
            return "Okay";
        }
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.passwordQuality);
    }



@Bindable
public TextWatcher getPasswordTextWatcher() {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            setPassword(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    };
}
```

And Finally

```
public class EditTextBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("textChangedListener")
    public static void bindTextWatcher(EditText editText, TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        editText.addTextChangedWatcher(textWatcher);
    }
}
```

But when I start to write onTextChanged method is not calling! can anyone help me to resolve this issue? thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your description of problem, it seems you did not initialized binding in your activity. if this is the case then

First check that you have initialized the binding in your activity and set the ViewModel on it like below

```
ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = null;
PasswordViewModel passwordViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    passwordViewModel = new PasswordViewModel();
    activityMainBinding.setViewModel(passwordViewModel);


}
```

Now the second problem is `addTextChangedWatcher`, add `addTextChangedListener` in place of that.

like this

```
 public class EditTextBindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter("textChangedListener")
    public static void bindTextWatcher(EditText editText, TextWatcher textWatcher) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini, I actually forget to initialize :( thanks for saving my time

Comment: Your Welcome!, actually previously this happened with me too ;-)